# DNS MX Record resolves fine from my servers, but is not cached/returned?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server

So, my DNS server is returning the MX records just fine:

```
DNS: avuna.org for type# 15 returned 0000046D61696C056176756E61036F7267
```

Has the proper records:

```
mail.avuna.org A 198.167.143.175
avuna.org MX 0 mail.avuna.org
```

And resolves just fine on MXLookup.

However, google DNS, and many other resolvers fail, and I don't know why. My TTL is 60 min as MX Lookup says.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that I note is that the delegation (in the org zone) looks like this:

```
avuna.org.              86400   IN      NS      ns3.avuna.org.
avuna.org.              86400   IN      NS      ns4.avuna.org.
avuna.org.              86400   IN      NS      ns2.avuna.org.
avuna.org.              86400   IN      NS      ns5.avuna.org.
avuna.org.              86400   IN      NS      ns1.avuna.org.
ns1.avuna.org.          86400   IN      A       198.167.143.175
ns2.avuna.org.          86400   IN      A       198.167.143.175
ns3.avuna.org.          86400   IN      A       198.167.143.175
ns4.avuna.org.          86400   IN      A       198.167.143.175
ns5.avuna.org.          86400   IN      A       198.167.143.175
```

And here's of course the glaringly obvious problem that while you have made up five different names for nameservers those all names resolve to the same address (according to these glue records), but then there's this:

```
$ dig @198.167.143.175 avuna.org NS +norec

; <<>> DiG 9.9.6-P1-RedHat-9.9.6-8.P1.fc21 <<>> @198.167.143.175 avuna.org NS +norec
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 44735
;; flags: qr aa; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;avuna.org.                     IN      NS

;; Query time: 167 msec
;; SERVER: 198.167.143.175#53(198.167.143.175)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr 16 18:44:24 UTC 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 27

$
```

The server at that address claims that there are no nameservers!

And this:

```
$ dig @198.167.143.175 ns1.avuna.org  +norec

; <<>> DiG 9.9.6-P1-RedHat-9.9.6-8.P1.fc21 <<>> @198.167.143.175 ns1.avuna.org +norec
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55802
;; flags: qr aa; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns1.avuna.org.                 IN      A

;; Query time: 162 msec
;; SERVER: 198.167.143.175#53(198.167.143.175)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr 16 18:45:45 UTC 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 31

$
```

The server at that address also claims that the names of the nameserver have no `A` records!

And to address the matter of an `MX` record I get this:

```
$ dig @198.167.143.175 avuna.org MX  +norec
;; Warning: Message parser reports malformed message packet.

; <<>> DiG 9.9.6-P1-RedHat-9.9.6-8.P1.fc21 <<>> @198.167.143.175 avuna.org MX +norec
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 15062
;; flags: qr aa; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: Message has 17 extra bytes at end

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;avuna.org.                     IN      MX

;; Query time: 162 msec
;; SERVER: 198.167.143.175#53(198.167.143.175)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr 16 18:49:18 UTC 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56

$
```

This actually takes the prize as it appears to not just deny existance of things that really ought to exist but actually sends something that appears to be invalidly formatted.

What kind of nameserver software is this? Does this actually fall under system administration or is this debugging of some work in progress implementation?

Comment: No `SOA` record either. Not even a `. SOA`. This is nowhere fit for production.

Comment: This is my own WIP implementation, but this is the information that I need to know. Thanks!

Comment: For others if anyone else gets this issue, it was an extension of no dots at the end of a FQDN. I forgot a null terminator(0x00) at the end of the FQDNs in an update.

Comment: @user3618509 Hate to say it, but if you aren't running DNS queries directly against your listener IP to troubleshoot problems, taking on a feat such as this is probably very premature. Writing a RFC compliant DNS server is an extremely large undertaking, and being able to troubleshoot them is pretty much a prerequisite.

Comment: @AndrewB It seems to be working now, I had tried testing with dig, but I hadn't thought of the <at>127.0.0.1 part. :)